# jOOQ Gradle plugin does not update generated files

Tags: java, gradle, jooq

For some reason I have to manually delete generated folder and run gradle task to get updated POJOs. Is this my setup, expected behavior or a bug? My setup is as follows:

```
jooq {
  library(sourceSets.main) {
    jdbc {
      driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
      url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library'
      user = 'library'
      password = '123'
      schema = 'library'
    }
    generator {
      name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator'
      strategy {
        name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
      }
      database {
        name = 'org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase'
        inputSchema = 'library'
      }
      generate {
        daos = true
      }
      target {
        packageName = 'com.example.library.db'
        directory = 'src/main/java'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you generate the jOOQ files? Please provide appropriate code from `build.gradle`.

Comment: @Opal Configuration added.

Comment: It would much better to add `src/main/generated` folder to not to mix both generated and source files. The mentioned folder should be added AS a source set and removed when `clean` task is run.

Comment: I am not intimate with Gradle. Do you mind dropping some code here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently when you generated the files they're added under `src/main/java` folder. This is not a good idea since you have mixed source and generated files. It's much better to add a separate folder `src/main/generated` and modify the `build.gradle` in the following way:

```
def generatedDir = 'src/main/generated'
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs += [generatedDir]
        }
    }
}

clean.doLast {
   project.file(generatedDir).deleteDir()
}
```

and change:

```
target {
   packageName = 'com.example.library.db'
   directory = generatedDir
}
```

This way you can easily manage the generated classes. All the classes will be removed automatically when `clean` task is run.

You also need to define a dependency between `compileJava` and the generator task. It can be done in the following way:

```
compileJava.dependsOn YOUR_GENERATOR_TASK_NAME
```

jOOQ will not delete the files automatically.

Comment: Perfect! Works as described.